# utility of asynchronous programming in web frameworks?

Tags: java, c#, asynchronous, web-frameworks

In both the C# and Java world, we can implement web controllers either with synchronous or asynchronous code. Following is a syntax example

### Java Spring MVC

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseObject doSomething() {
        ----
        return new ReponseObject();
    }

    public Future<ResponseObject> doSomethingAsync() {
        -----
        return AsyncTask.forValue(new ReponseObject());
    }
}
```

### C# ASP.NET MVC

```
[Controller]
public class Controller {

    public ActionResult DoSomething(){
        -------
        return Json(new ResponseObject());
    }


    public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomethingAsync(){
        -------
        return Json(new ResponseObject());
    }

}
```

From my current knowledge, this is what happens on both platforms when a request is received

- In the synchronous case, the thread that was dispatched to serve the web request is busy serving the request, which could take up some time and if the number of threads the server allocates for workers gets exhausted, new clients will have to wait (call it Slashdot effect or DoS)
- In the asynchronous case, the worker thread determines that the operation is deferred and assigns a task executor the duty of serving the request, then serves a new request

In both cases, single requests do **not** get a performance increase if their body is basically copied and pasted between synchronous and asynchronous version. I mean, if you don't parallelize I/O operations by code (e.g. using threads or more `Future`s **within** the method body) you don't get any performance improvement

### The question

I simply want to ask, from a top-level view, what is the real advantage of employing such asynchronous way of developing web services considering that massive amount of requests will simply exhaust the worker executor's capacity instead of the application server pool. For example in Spring for Java, a thread in the DispatherServlet will be released in favour of a thread pool that has limited capacity. In .NET, tasks and threads are slightly different but the task executor has still limited capacity.

In other words, wouldn't it be simpler to tune the application server's thread pool capacity rather than using an additional layer of abstraction?

Or is there something I don't know yet about asynchronous programming? Why can't I understand its benefits in these kinds of scenarios?

Comment: For .NET this can help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx

Comment: And this describes the solved problems with Servlet 3.0 pretty well: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/java-concurrency-asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html

Comment: It's only useful if you're doing IO so your thread doesn't have to be blocked while waiting for the IO to finish.

Comment: And it's useful because you can server more requests than on a traditional thread based model

Comment: @simas_ch I don't agree. My question wants to point out that having an additional executor is equivalent to increasing the app server's thread pool. If requests scale, asynchronous programming eventually leads to memory exhaustion, and all schedulers have limited queue capacity, so eventually requests will be queued. Reading the articles soon...

Comment: No it's not because of non blocking IO. Please read the articles.

Comment: The .NET article may contain the answer: "Why Not Increase the Thread Pool Size?". Once I have read both I will try to expand an answer. Thank you all